# Relate one node to another node

Tags: java, data-structures

Is the following code:

```
class FamilyMember{
   String name;
   String type;
}

class Family{
   FamilyMember father;
   FamilyMemeber mother;
   List<FamilyMember> children;
}
```

will produces the following relationship:

```
 +------------------+      +------------------+  
 |     Father       |------|     Mother       |  
 +------------------+  ^   +------------------+  
                       |                  
                       |                  
                       |                  
                       |                  
                       |                    
                 --------------       
                 |            |                   
                 |            |                   
                 |            |                   
                 |            |                   
 +------------------+       +------------------+  
 |     Son          |       |    Daughter      |  
 +------------------+       +------------------+
```

Since the Number of children are different in different family, therefore every family have its own family structure.

I want to make the **class** which can shows the above relationship with variable number of children.

Comment: So? Have a Family class that has two parents and a list of children. Maybe you are mixing up family trees and class relations? Because they don't relate directly to one another.

Comment: This looks like an awfully confusing example from a lecture trying to explain inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class FamilyMember{
   String name;
   String type;
}

class Family{
   FamilyMember father;
   FamilyMemeber mother;
   List<FamilyMember> children;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a simple tree with parent/child relations. Each node in the tree is a person.

Don't forget that;

1. Its possible for two children to share only one common parent, not both. EG a man can have two children with different women, and vice versa.
2. All parents are implicitly children themselves.
3. Each child will have *two* parents instead of the normal *one*.

A class with the following data should suffice;

```
public class Person {

  boolean female;
  Person father;
  Person mother;
  List<Person> children;

}
```

Comment: An `enum` would be a cleaner way to implement the `sex` of the `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a Class called Family?
Which can have multiple (n) children and 1 or 0 (sad world :/) father & mother.

You could also link every child to a specific mother and father.

Actually I would rather choose a class Person which has a gender and all other classes should inherit from it. Since there are multiple things each person has like name and stuff this should be easier to handle on the long run...

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent
{
    String name;
    String gender;
}

class Family
{
    Map<Set<Parent, Parent>, String> child;
}
```